# posting to FaceBook wall using the C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

My users login to Facebook through JavaScript and an Ajax/JSON call, and I check that the username is in our DB through a web-service. If successful, a Facebook cookie is created and the user is logged in.

No SDK has been used this far.

Now, using the SDK, I want to allow the user to post a message to their wall after they've successfully uploaded a file. Already handling file upload, it's working. Upon upload success, I want to use the SDK to post a message to the user's wall with a link to the uploaded file.

Can I access that cookie info, because the user is already logged in, via the SDK and use what is necessary to post to the wall?

If so, can anyone point me at a sample?

Answer (score 0):

By Facebook SDK, do you mean Facebook Open Graph API?  Here's a link the facebook documentations on [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/), also I did a screencast series on getting started with the open graph - [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8D1E905D80087F6F).

The basic idea is that you create objects ('file to be uploaded', in your case) and actions ('successful file upload', in your case) which you wire to your application and which post information to the authorized user's facebook timeline, newsfeed or ticker.

Comment: Actually using the FB C# SDK but I'll certainly take a look at what you've done. Thanks!